# How to read data from an array of atoms in Jotai state management library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jotai

I have an array of atoms, I need to get the data from each of those atoms and store it in a new array.

As you can see in the image I am getting an array of atoms from requestAtoms and then I have to create a new array from the atoms that I get from request atoms that should contain data (not the atoms) and then I want to post it to the backend.

[image]

I want to handle this in an handle submit function and since I can not use hooks inside JavaScript function I can not use useAtom in handleSubmit and even if I use useAtom outside how can I iterate over each atom and apply useAtom on it.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with Jotai and especially with Hooks, you can't put `useAtom` in the loop and update individual elements when iterating over your list. What you could do, is to create a "derived" atom, that is backend by a list of another atoms and then update this derived atom, so that it updates its underlying collection of atoms.